# AWS Control Tower and Organizations

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-organizations, aws-control-tower

I have used AWS Control Tower and Organizations in order to create three different Environment (dev, test and prod) account. It worked great for two of the three accounts butt for some reason. My test account isn't showing up under "Service Catalog" > "Provisioned products". I can see my other two accounts there.

Under "AWS Control Tower" > "Accounts" the account has the error message: "Enrollment failed".

My problem is that because I can't see the account under the "Service Catalog" I am also unable to delete it and try again.

How do I undo this to start fresh?